# Student Uplift data extraction in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing a project with Kindergarten kids in Thailand to improve English. One of the things I want to do is measure "uplift" that a lecture brings to the students.

Teacher scores 3 students before the lecture, and then scores all students as usual after the lecture. For uplift, we want to measure the difference before and after using python / pandas.

I can split easily the big df to one per name (sample below)..

basically I want per row look up a name, and then look up the post lecture score in the column - row by row ( so end results is ie Pre Score and Post Score for that name in the row.

Just want the left hand cols and Pre and post score for the named student

a bit confused how to do...thanks

[image: Uplift raw data]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for old pandas versions with [`DataFrame.lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
df['new'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Name'])
```

In last pandas versions use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then filter if match columns `Name` with `variable` column in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
melt = df.melt('Name', ignore_index=False)

df['new'] = melt.loc[melt['Name'] == melt['variable'], 'value']
```

Comment: Very much appreciated....  new to melt ( first time hearing it ) .... what do I use for variable and value ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> melt = df.melt('Name', ignore_index=False)

df['new'] = melt.loc[melt['Name'] == melt['variable'], 'value']

Thanks,not Sure what to put in variable and value